# Añadir datos intermedios

Tags: r

¿Existe alguna librería en R dónde puedas indicar el número de filas a añadir (2,3,4,600 etc) y que te añada datos intermedios entre filas?

Por ejemplo, tengo estos datos:

```
  df <- read.table(text = '
    municipio   año poblacion
    mun1    2000    100
    mun1    2001    200
    mun1    2002    300
    mun2    2000    1550
    mun2    2001    500
    mun2    2002    3000
    ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero añadir por ejemplo 2 filas extras entre los datos de forma proporcional.

Es decir, meter 2 datos entre 100 y 200.

Sería aproximadamente 100-133-166-200.
Ha metido 133 y 166 como nuevos datos.

Entre los datos 1500 y 500 sería
(1500-500)/3 = 350.
Pues los nuevos datos irían de 350 en 350:

1500-1200-850-500

Al final quedaría algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrías resolverlo así:

```
library(tidyverse)

rows_by_group <- 3

df %>%
  arrange(municipio, año) %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate(next_año = lead(año, 1)) %>% 
  expand_grid(n = 0:(rows_by_group -1)) %>% 
  left_join(df, by = c("municipio", 
                       "next_año" = "año"),
            suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(p = poblacion + ((poblacion.y - poblacion) / rows_by_group) * n,
         p = if_else(is.na(p), poblacion*1.0, p)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(next_año) | n == 0) %>% 
  select(municipio, año, poblacion = p)

# A tibble: 14 × 3
   municipio   año poblacion
   <chr>     <int>     <dbl>
 1 mun1       2000      100 
 2 mun1       2000      133.
 3 mun1       2000      167.
 4 mun1       2001      200 
 5 mun1       2001      233.
 6 mun1       2001      267.
 7 mun1       2002      300 
 8 mun2       2000     1550 
 9 mun2       2000     1200 
10 mun2       2000      850 
11 mun2       2001      500 
12 mun2       2001     1333.
13 mun2       2001     2167.
14 mun2       2002     3000
```

Comentarios:

- Ordenamos con `arrange()`
- Agrupamos por `municipio`
- Obtenemos el siguiente año por cada fila
- Expandimos cada fila por la cantidad de `rows_by_group` definida
- Hacemos un `left_join` con el mismo `data.frame` para obtener la población del año siguiente
- Calculamos el incremento de la población en cada fila entre año y año + 1
- Quitamos las últimas filas de cada grupo que no participan en está lógica.

Comment: Tengo q estudiar este codigo detenidamente, mucho q asimilar jaja. Impresionante.

Comment: Tengo una duda, cuando hargo un csv de 2000 registros y pruebo el codigo, me sale este error:Error in `auto_copy()`:
! `x` and `y` must
  share the same src.
ℹ set `copy` = TRUE (may be
  slow).

Me sale en la parte de left_join,
Pero si ahora cargo el ejemplo que he puesto aqui, ejecuto el codigo (funciona) y pruebo otra vez  los datos ya funciona. Es decir, antes de ejecutar los datos reales tengo que ejecutar unos datos falsos para que funcione. ¿Eso por qué pasa? Es como si no leyera bien el csv

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que cuando no funciona, cargo otros datos, ejecuto y funciona con datos falsos, vuelvo a ejecutar en los datos reales y funciona, las cuentas no las hace bien. Osea funciona pero no como debería. Luego he probado a cargar los datos como en este ejemplo, con el read.table(text = ' y pegar todo el contenido del csv, y ahora es cuando el codigo funciona y hace bien las cuentas. Muy raro todo.

Comment: Tendría que ver los datos reales, si pudieras compartirlos los miro.

Comment: Creo que el fallo esta en el fichero en sí, tal vez por combinar linux-windows. En otra pregunta me pusiste una manera de hacer tasas de variación y en algunas celdas las cuentas no las hacia bien. Tal vez haya un símbolo o espacio en blanco en algunas celdas q no se ven a simple vista. Tengo que investigarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa usando `seq` y `unnest`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  arrange(municipio, año) %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>%   #Para separar los inicios y fines
  mutate(siguiente = lead(poblacion, default = 0),   #Sirve para hacer la secuencia y para el filtrado más adelante. 
         secuencia = map2(.x = poblacion,            #Una lista dentro de un data.frame
                          .y = siguiente, 
                          ~seq(from = .x, to = .y, length = 4))) %>% 
  unnest(secuencia) %>%                               #Desanido la lista y creo más filas.
  filter(siguiente != 0) %>%                          #Elimino las secuencias que van a cero por ser el último dato de la serie. seq() da error y no NA cuando se encuentra con NA, de lo contrario no lo necesitaría. 
#Lo que sigue es bastante adhoc, básicamente saco datos repetidos
  filter(secuencia != lead(secuencia, default = 0)) %>% 
  select(municipio, año, poblacion = secuencia)
```

La idea es simple, separar por grupos, generar una lista de secuencias de largo 4 entre cada valor de población y el siguiente y desanidar la secuencia.

Tiene una complicación: `seq()` no funciona con NA como lo suelen hacer otras funciones de `R`, da un error en lugar de regresar NA. Entonces en el `lead`  tengo indicar que el default es 0 y generar secuencias innecesarias que después tengo que filtrar. Se resuelve con un filter y no debería ser problemático siempre que no haya combinaciones de municipio/año con el valor observado (real) 0.

La otra complicación es que se repiten valores porque están al final de una de las secuencias y al principio de las siguientes. De nuevo, filtro muy ad hoc: eliminar una fila de si identica a la siguiente. Fallo obvio: la fila siguiente es EN VERDAD igual porque dos combinaciones de municipio/año son iguales.

Comment: muchas gracias! tendré que analizarlo pasito a pasito para ver como funciona todo.